# About LSTM structure for classification ( in this case, it's Sentiment Analysis)

Tags: python, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to understand how LSTM can solve a Sentiment Analysis problem. Currently, I'm confused by this structure: [image: LSTM unrolled architecture]

So here is my list of questions:

- After you feed the LSTM layer with vectors which represent each word of each sentence of the dataset, what does the LSTM layer do with them and what is the output?
- What does the forget gate do? For example, there are 50 vectors to represent the word "good", so it just forgets unnecessary vectors or something?
- Why there are two LSTM layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After you fed LSTM layer with vectors which represented each words of each sentences of the dataset, what does LSTM layer do with them and what is the output?

The final output of the architecture you show (up to the point it is fed into the softmax) is a sentence embedding, i.e. a single (high-dimensional) floating-point vector that represents the sentence. (You showed the unrolled version, but I find it useful to be simultaneously thinking of its real rolled up form, too.)

As far as this question goes, it is doing the same thing as a simple RNN, so make sure you understand that first. There are a lot of articles and videos explaining it. E.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/animated-rnn-lstm-and-gru-ef124d06cf45

> What does the forget gate do?

It tries to learn which are the more important words. If being trained for sentiment analysis it will hopefully learn to give more weight to words that are emotive, and less weight to the words carrying no sentiment. You might also see it called a keep gate. When the weight is high it keeps the word, when the weight is low it forgets the word.

Say you had a long sentence like: "This movie has some really funny characters and superb action scenes, and was directed by Tom Smith, produced by Dick Jones, and began production in 2019."  The problem here for an RNN doing sentiment analysis is that it maintains state one word at a time. Each step it loses a bit of what went before. By the end it has all but forgotten the positive early words.

You really want it seen as: "really funny characters, superb action scenes.". That is a much shorter sentence to learn and understand. So this is what the forget gate in an LSTM is trying to do for you.

Spoiler alert: It does not do it that well, but it is distinctly better than not doing it at all.

> Why there are two LSTM layers?

To allow more sophisticated understanding and better sentence embeddings. It is the same as adding another layer in a fully-connected neural network. LSTMs don't scale very well beyond two layers however.

> how the model know that sentence's sentiment base on that vector exactly?
> Does that vector have some kind of features that make it positive or negative

The answer to your second sub-question is "maybe, but not always in a human-readable form". What the very last layer of your architecture is doing is trying to learn what kind of sentiment each element of the vector indicates, using a classic fully-connected neural net.

E.g. say you use vectors of dimension 100, and you want to classify into three classes: angry, happy, sad. Your training data then has sentences like "Everything went smoothly today" with a label of "happy". Maybe that sentence has a high number in element 77 of the vector the LSTM produces. Maybe most of the "happy" sentences have a high value in that element, but the angry and sad sentences show no pattern for it. So it gives a high positive weight connecting element 77 to the happy output, and a zero weight connecting 77 to each of angry and sad.

If your goal is improving your intuition, it can be interesting to build models with just 2 or 3 dimensions, and just a few training sentences, and then deliberately overfit the model on your training data. Sometimes you get noise, but sometimes you get lucky and can follow through how the vectors for each word interact, to give a different pattern in the output, and how the final layer combines them to give a prediction.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for replying but I have one more question left and I hope you answer it as well. So I get that the output of LSTM layer is a vector that represents the input sentence, but how the model know that sentence's sentiment base on that vector exactly? Does that vector have some kind of features that make it positive or negative?

Comment: @Gorg I've appended another section to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: One more question, I promised. So when we tried to predict a new sentence, the model knows how to give weight to each element of that sentence to label the sentiment right?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. It will be a bit rough, especially with words it didn't see much in the training data.

Comment: I'm really sorry for bothering you again so soon but I just realized I have more question and I have no idea if this will be the last. I understand how RNNs work with vector because it only has 1 tanh function to transform each value of the vector into between 1 and -1. But with LSTMs and its gates, I'm just confused. Can you tell me what those LSTM blocks do with word's vector?

Comment: @Gorg (I was going to say you could just mark this as answered, and start a new question; but, to be fair, this is still the same question, isn't it.) You have choices here. 1. Treat LSTMs as magical black boxes that have more moving parts, and more learnable weights, than RNNs and can therefore learn a more sophisticated representation; 2. What I suggested at the end of my answer: build a really small LSTM, and then step through in a debugger (or with verbose logging), to see what is going on at every step of the way. I.e. is your purpose to use them, or deeply understand them?

Comment: @Gorg Personally, either way, I'd move on to studying attention, which can be thought of as a better way to solve the problem that LSTM's extra gates are trying to solve, and that would lead you to Transformers, which are, most of the time, a better architecture for anything you would consider an LSTM for.

Comment: I just want to understand LSTM the way this video explains how normal Neural Network work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfmFfD2RIcg . Most people say the same thing when they explained LSTM: "Cell state contains past information, forget gate can choose to forget or keep certain information..." but none of them demonstrate how LSTM work in Neural Network form.